# How is かって being used here?

Tags: grammar

いつまでに送ればいい**かって**いうことですよ。

I can kind of get whats going on here. Forgive me if I'm mistaken but I think it means "When are you expected to send this **thing**, is what I mean".

I don't understand how かって fits here; the dictionary came up with a lot of words similar to かって, but none of them would make sense if I applied them here.

I also went to Google Translate and it decided to group かっていう together and translate it as "I mean" but isn't that implied with いう in the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`かって` in this sentence is not one unit, but two. `か` and `って`.

It might be easier to see like this:

> いつまでに送ればいいか、っていうことですよ。

- **か** is the question particle.
- **って** is an alternate form of と, a quotative particle.

Comment: How does it work at the end of a question like, なんでそんなことするかって？

Answer (score 0):

To build on rintaun's answer, think of it as being delimited in quotes (er, kakko, whatever):

> 「いつまでに送ればいいか」ということですよ。

Unpunctuated, pure Hiragana without spaces is actually *really* hard to read because of ambiguities of this form and the army of homophones. (Trying to read Romaji is even more confusing.)